# Rails engine with --full option model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I tried to separate my model, `User`, as a Rails engine, in order to use it in more then one application.

To achieve this I created an engine with `rails plugin new engine_name --full` so that I can use all the routes and models without mounting in an isolated namespace.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  scope :find_user, ->(id) { where(id: id)}

  def self.say_hello(str)
    puts "Welcome #{str}"
  end
end
```

This is my `User` model. It is not namespaced in a module because the engine was created with `--full`.

I can successfully include this into any Rails app and can access the routes.

I can access class methods:

```
2.1.5 :015 > User.say_hello("ferdy")
Welcome ferdy
```

But when I try to invoke the `create` class method I get an error:

```
User.create(email:"ferdsfd@sdfds.com",password:12345678)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
```

Comment: run ``rake db:create`` and ``rake db:migrate``

Comment: `create` requires a table to get a list of columns from, which are exposed as attributes of the model. As @ProsenjitSaha said migrate the database to have the table, users, created.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i wouldn't isolate the whole model to the gem, because it depends on the schema of your app. I would suggest you to separate the common methods for the `User` model to a concern, move the concern to the gem, and include it in models of your apps, where you need it.